# Change " Magento Commerce " from my links

Tags: php, url, seo

I have a magento website Mypet.com.pk .When I search in google for mypet.com.pk it shows the title "Magento Commerce" written with all my links e.g.
Home page - Magento Commerce. Can anyone help me to change it to my domain name? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your domain name or what you want to here.

```
System->Configuration->General->Design->Html Head->Default Title
```

set value according to your requirement, see screenshot.

[image]

Comment: I've already done this but my problem is different please write site:www.mypet.com.pk in google and will know. It will show "Magento Commerce" written with all my links. I wish to change it with my company name

Comment: @NadiaBhatti I try with google, but not find as you told.